# Titles not being added to locations for the directions url on google maps app on certain phones

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an application that uses latitude/longitude to send a url to the google maps app and navigate someone to that location.  I wrap the actual address name in parenthesis at the end so the proper address still shows up.  Something like this:

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" current location  + "&daddr=" final lat and lng + "(" + name of address + ")";
```

Now my problem is that on some of my test devices, the address properly shows up; however, I have a Samsung Rugby Pro as one of my test devices for which the full address does not show up.  The address *does* show up on other Samsung devices I've tested, so I'm running out of suspicions for what could be causing the problem on only one device.  All devices are running the  most current version of Android and Maps.  Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Is the device also running the most current version of Google Play Services? Google Maps might hook into that for some of its functionality.

Comment: Hi @NasaGeek thanks for your reply.  A few of the devices I use for testing belong to my clients and aren't logged in with a google account.  I will try and get an account to log in with from them and make sure the Play Services are up to date.  I'm not sure this is the issue though, as the company using this particular device in question sees the issue too and is most likely up to date on their own devices.  I will get back to you :)